# Show that equation has no rational solutions

Tags: rationality-testing

How do I prove that the equation $a^2-2b^2-3c^2+6d^2=0$ has no non trivial rational solutions?

What techniques are there to solve general problems like this?

Comment: if there are rational solutions with some of the variables nonzero, there are integer solutions. Next, if there are integer solutions with some of $a,b,c,d \neq 0,$  then there are such with $\gcd(a,b,c,d) = 1$  Anyway, you need a degree of comfort with quadratic forms  over the integers.

Comment: tell you what:  Since $a^2 - 2 b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$

Comment: @WillJagy: what if $a$ and $b$ are both divisible by $3$?

Comment: @TonyK   right. But then $a^2 - 2 b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 9,$   and  $3c^2 - 6 d^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 9,$  so that

Comment: @WillJagy: that works for me :-)

Comment: @WillJagy unfortunately, I have no degree of comfort of quadratic forms over integers. Could you point in the direction of literature?

Comment: inspector,  I like Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms. The thing you need to be able to prove is that, for integers $u,v,$  if $u^2 - 2 v^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3,$  then both $u,v \equiv 0 \pmod 3,$ so that $3 | \gcd(u,v)$ and actually $u^2 - 2 v^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 9.$  This is general for binary quadratic form $e u^2 + f uv + g v^2$   with discriminant $\Delta = f^2 - 4eg,$   given a prime $q$   that does not divide $\Delta,$  if Legendre $ (|\Delta|q) = -1$ and  $e u^2 + f uv + g v^2  \equiv 0 \pmod q,$   then both $u,v \equiv 0 \pmod q$

Comment: @WillJagy So if we've shown that $a^2-2b^2\equiv 0 (mod 3)$ and $ (mod 9)$ how does this help to prove there are no non trivial integer solutions?

Comment: then $3c^2  - 6 d^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 9,$ that is   $c^2  - 2 d^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3,$   so that $c,d \equiv 0 \pmod 3$  Thus  $3|\gcd(a,b,c,d)$   This contradicts the original assumption that  $\gcd(a,b,c,d) = 1$

Comment: Essentially it's Fermat's method of infinite descent. (Rephrasing Will's comments) We have $a^2 - 2b^2 = 3(c^2 - 2d^2)$ which implies $ a = 3a_1, b = 3b_1$ (which we can show by checking values mod 3) and so $ 3(a_1^2 - 2b_1^2 ) = c^2 - 2d^2$ which implies $ c = 3c_1, d = 3d_1$ and so on.